# Oracle: Get records updated after specific dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to find the records which are updated after specific date but don't have column of `update_date`.

While searching I found that Oracle 10g came to now that `ORA_ROWSCN` can be useful.

`SELECT ORA_ROWSCN, last_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = 188;`

But I think it is useful for specific row.

Let me know how should I implement this?

pls help

Answer (score 1):

If you want this information, then you should include `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns in the table.  These are just good ideas for any tables in even semi-production systems, so this information is readily available.

You should also be doing backups, which can be used to identify what has changed.  Oracle audit tables are another feature that could help.

There are known issues with using `ora_rowscn` the way you want to use it.  [Here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:517105100346104196) is one discussion.

Of course, proper columns, back ups, and audits are of no help *now* if they haven't already been implemented.  The function `scn_to_timestamp()` can be used to convert the internal scn number to a timestamp.  Read about it [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:517105100346104196).  However, this should be viewed as a desperation measure.  Using it should encourage you to implement more reliable methods for keeping track of database changes.